# The final local variable dc cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Tags: java, variables, local-variables

```
public static void createTable() {
    final DatabaseConnection dc;
    final Connection con;
    final String que;
    Statement state;
    new Thread(() -> {
        dc = new DatabaseConnection("check_table_exists");
        con = dc.con;
        que = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DatabaseConnection.TABLE + " (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,itemId INT(200), itemName VARCHAR(200), amount INT(200),uuid VARCHAR(200), timestamp BIGINT(200), PRIMARY KEY (id))";
        try {
            state = con.createStatement();
            state.execute(que);
            state.close();
            dc.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            dc.close();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I was just wondering as to how I can solve this problem. I am also receiving an error 'Local variable state defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final' on the 'state' variable. I believe this is because I am using some old source code I found, however, I cannot seem to find the solution.

Comment: I have fixed the above 'Local variable state defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final', however, I am now receiving the following issue - 'The final local variable state cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type'

Comment: `final DatabaseConnection dc = new DatabaseConnection("check_table_exists");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Java, you cannot assign anything to a variable marked as `final` except in declaration. On the other hand, you need these variable to be final to be used in this closure. This may feel frustrating after JS. So what you may need to do with this particular code is to move variable declarations into closure, removing `final` modifier. If you still need to access them from outside, you are likely to define a class that implements `Runnable` interface, and make these variable to be fields of this class instances though get methods.

Also, do you really need this code to run asynchronously?

Comment: Actually, you cannot assign anything more than once.

Comment: Managed to get it all figured out as it is, thank you.

Comment: @StoxMC good to hear! You may also want post your own solution and mark as the best answer, if it differs from the suggested.